# How to get a UNIVERSAL Windows batch file timestamp

Tags: batch-file, timestamp

I'm having trouble generating a timestamp in a Windows batch file, because I get diferent date formats on different Windows versions.

My machine:

```
>echo %date%
>Tue 11/17/2009
```

Friends machine:

```
>echo %date%
>11/17/2009
```

I guess there has to be some way of getting the date (11/17/2009) from both strings using for /f. I've been trying and googling and can't find the answer.

Is there another way to get a timestamp without using %date%?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [VBScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript) if you want to get independent date time settings:

```
thedate = Now
yr = Year(thedate)
mth = Month(thedate)
dy = Day(thedate)
hr = Hour(thedate)
min = Minute(thedate)
sec = Second(thedate)
WScript.Echo yr&mth&dy&hr&min&sec
```

Comment: This is really usefull used inside the script by:

>cscript date.vbs //Nologo

(where date.vbs contains the code you included)

Comment: Doesn't this just return the local datetime?  The question was to generate the UTC datetime - and is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [doff.exe](http://www.jfitz.com/dos/index.html#DOFF). I use this a lot for getting timestamps for naming log files. From its web site:

> DOFF prints a formatted date and time, with an optional date offset, (e.g -1 prints yesterday's date, +1 prints tomorrow's date). To view all the options available, execute "doff -h". I typically use this utility for renaming log files so that they include a timestamp, (see the third example below). This code should compile under Unix/Linux, as well as DOS.
>
> Sample commands:

```
C:\>doff
19991108131135
```

> With no parameters the output is the current date/time in the following format: yyyymmddhhmiss

```
C:\>doff mm/dd/yyyy
11/08/1999
```

> In the above example a date format specification is given.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/ " %%a in ('doff mm/dd/yyyy -1') do (
set mm=%%a
set dd=%%b
set yyyy=%%c)
rename httpd-access.log httpd-access-%yyyy%%mm%%dd%.log
```

> The sample batch file above shows a neat way to rename a log file based on yesterday's date. The "for" command executes doff to print yesterday's date, (the "-1" parameter specifies yesterday), then extracts each component of the date into DOS batch file variables. The "rename" command renames "httpd-access.log" to "httpd-access-[yesterday's date].log"

---

Also check out Microsoft's now.exe, available in the [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd). One bad thing I found out (the hard way) about it is it sets the ERRORLEVEL to the number of characters printed.

Looks like this:

```
c:\>now

Thu May 19 14:26:45 2011
```

Help:

```
NOW   :  Display Message with Current Date and Time

Usage : NOW [message to be printed with time-stamp]

    NOW displays the current time, followed by its command-line arguments.
    NOW is similar to the standard ECHO command, but with a time-stamp.
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it can't be done directly, so you need to resort to hacks like *[GetDate.cmd](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-getdate.html)*.

There are lots of VBScript and small external commandline tools available too, which isn't something I'd take a dependency on unless you're already using something of that nature in your overall system.

Personally, I'd be trying to route around it by using PowerShell which neatly sidesteps the issue completely.

Comment: This is a great thought but what sort of PowerShell code would do this?

Comment: @Jim2B In PS, you can get an object via [DateTime]::UtcNow and then party on that (e.g. it has a Month property etc). Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VBScript. You can do it with something like this:

```
echo %date:~-10,2%/%date:~-7,2%/%date:~-4,4%
```

[Source](http://www.intelliadmin.com/index.php/2007/02/create-a-date-and-time-stamp-in-your-batch-files/)

Comment: doesn't this assume the format of the date variable's output?

Comment: Yup, this assumes the local date formatting is of a certain format.

Answer (score 0):

As I have posted in here:
[Batch: Timestamp to UNIX Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11385030/batch-timestamp-to-unix-time)

What about simple 1-line long C program returning UNIX timestamp? You can retrieve value from %errorlevel% in batch script.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    return (int) time(NULL);
}
```

In my test in command prompt it worked:

```
C:\Users\dabaran\Desktop\cs50\src\C>.\time || echo %errorlevel% && set mytstamp=%errorlevel%
1419609373

C:\Users\dabaran\Desktop\cs50\src\C>echo %mytstamp%
1419609373
```