# Defining a variable in a batch file not working

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file that looks like the following:

```
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %a in ('date /t') do (set newdate=%c%a%b)
blat my_file_%newdate% -to test@email.com -f test_email.com
```

When I enter this two commands separately in a cmd window, it seems to work perfectly fine, but when placed into a batch file and ran manually, it does not work.

Comment: if you look for a language independent method to get the date string, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18024049/2152082)

Comment: In a batch file you will need to double the percent characters, `%a`, `%b` and `%c` become `%%a`, `%%b` and `%%c` respectively.

Comment: Mofi's answer below is a direct quote from the help file for the `FOR` command.  Please consider reading the help file in the future before asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

Open a command prompt window and run `for /?`. Output is the help for this command containing at top the information:

> To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead
>   of %variable.  Variable names are case sensitive, so %i is different from %I.

Next I suggest to run `set /?` and read at least last page of output help listing the environment variable `DATE`.

> If Command Extensions are enabled, then there are several dynamic
>   environment variables that can be expanded but which don't show up
>   in the list of variables displayed by SET.  These variable values are
>   computed dynamically each time the value of the variable is expanded.
>   If the user explicitly defines a variable with one of these names, then
>   that definition will override the dynamic one described below:
>
> %CD% - expands to the current directory string.
>
> %DATE% - expands to current date using same format as DATE command.
>
> %TIME% - expands to current time using same format as TIME command.
>
> %RANDOM% - expands to a random decimal number between 0 and 32767.
>
> %ERRORLEVEL% - expands to the current ERRORLEVEL value
>
> %CMDEXTVERSION% - expands to the current Command Processor Extensions
>       version number.
>
> %CMDCMDLINE% - expands to the original command line that invoked the
>       Command Processor.
>
> %HIGHESTNUMANODENUMBER% - expands to the highest NUMA node number
>       on this machine.

So there is perhaps no need to run in a separate command process in background with `cmd.exe /C` the command line `date /T` as done by **FOR** with the posted command line, capture output of this command process, and process it line by line by **FOR**.

Well, the format of date output by `date /T` or on using `%DATE%` depends on Windows region setting. And it was not posted what is the date format on used machine with used account. But I suppose that following works also a very little bit faster.

```
for /F "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ("%DATE%") do set "newdate=%%c%%a%%b"
```

I suppose using only string substitution works also on your machine for your account with a date format `MM/dd/yyyy` or `dddd, MM/dd/yyyy`:

```
set "newdate=%DATE:~-4%%DATE:~-10,2%%DATE:~-7,2%"
```

This last solution is some microseconds faster than the others.

There is also a region independent solution as explained in detail for example by the answer on [Why does %date% produce a different result in batch file executed as scheduled task?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44670322/3074564) But the region independent solution using **WMIC** is much slower in comparison to the usage of the dynamic environment variable `DATE`.

Answer (score 0):

Batch variable need to have %% instead of only one

Comment: what do you mean? So it should be my_file_%%newdate%%

Comment: not environment variables (`%var%`). It's just the `for` variables (`%%a` ...) that have to be adapted. (described in the second paragraph in `for /?`)

Comment: Mark post as answer :)

Comment: @LéoRoueire make your answer clearer before  `;)` (you may use the info from my previous comment)

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are looking for the output to be YYMMDD, if so try this:

```
For /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set newdate=%%c%%a%%b)
```